# Easy Way to Show/Hide Individual Divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my website I have divs that toggle whenever you click one, shown in this js fiddle: [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16xxp34e/).

The HTML

```
<body>

<div class="class1">Div 1</div>
<div class="class2">Div 2</div>

<div class="class1">Div 3</div>
<div class="class2">Div 4</div>

<div class="class1">Div 5</div>
<div class="class2">Div 6</div>

<div class="class1">Div 7</div>
<div class="class2">Div 8</div>

</body>
```

Lil CSS

```
.class2{display: none;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".class1").click(function(){
    $(".class2").show();
    $(".class1").hide();
});
$(".class2").click(function(){
    $(".class1").show();
    $(".class2").hide();
});
});
```

Now I want it so that when I click on a Div, for example Div 1, Div 2 shows up, but unlike the js fiddle I want it so that Divs 4, 6, and 8 also don't show. I know I can do that by giving each div a unique class or id but that would take a lot of time since I'm working with, say, 100 divs. If there's any easy way to just click one div and toggle it with another without all the rest also  switching. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/16xxp34e/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    $(".class2").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    });
});
```

Use `.next()` and `.prev()`. Assuming that you want to toggle next and previous elements